# gnome-terminal doesn't work maybe because of locale setting

Tags: locale, gnome, archlinux, gnome-terminal

I installed Antergos (easy version of Arch) with the Japanese environment.
But I wanted to chaned the language to English, so I reffer [the wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) then run some commands after uncomment `#en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen` and edit `/etc/locale.conf` into following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The problem starts from here.

I restarted my computer and found that gnome-terminal doesn't work.
I substituted eshell on Emacs and run `gnome-terminal` command, then got error messages:

```
(process:1202): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

The output of `locale` command is following:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ja_JP.utf8
LC_TIME=ja_JP.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ja_JP.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ja_JP.utf8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What changes some part of locale setting into Japanese? Or other reasons which terminate gnome-terminal exist?

I have tried solutions sugestted here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180103 .

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem some time ago. I fixed my locale config running this command

```
sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting Error code 9, And this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: saved my day. could not get access to my terminal because of this error.

Comment: Great!!! After upgrading my glibc, the terminal ui cannot work. Fixed it by this command.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of status code `8` is documented on gnome's website [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ):

> The environment that gnome-terminal-server is started with does not
>   correctly set the locale to a UTF-8 locale. Consult your
>   distribution's documentation on how to fix this. Note that is it not
>   relevant to check the locale settings from a different terminal (e.g.
>   xterm); what counts is the environment that the session dbus-daemon
>   passes to the processes it starts.

So you're right, this is probably due to locale settings. I don't quite understand all the details, but if I set `~/.xinitrc` to `exec gnome-session` and then run `startx`, I get a similar error to yours.

However, if instead of running `startx`, I start the `gdm` display manager (via `systemctl start gdm.service` on Arch), I can spawn a `gnome-terminal` correctly. So if you're okay with using gdm, that may be a solution. Lightdm also works, though SLiM doesn't (from my experience).

In the past, I also had to install the `vte3` package for `gnome-terminal` to work, so make sure that's installed as well. And FWIW, `sudo gnome-terminal` seems to always work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to regenerate your locales after you had edited your `/etc/locale.gen` file ?

> locale-gen

I think in your explanation you mixed the `/etc/locale.gen` and the `/etc/locale.conf` files. Be sure you edited the correct file with the correct values.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken them in question. They are correct on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how I solved it;
`sudo locale-gen --purge --no-archive`

Then; `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing with locale worked for me. Once changed back the default python version (3.5 on ubuntu16), terminal worked just fine.